# Get transaction before confirmation

Tags: send-transaction, fees

I want to know a way to get the transaction details just after the transaction.
For instance i transfer some sol from one address to another and in response i get the transaction hash. In the very next second if i hit the `getConfirmedTransaction` or `getSignatureStatus` i have null in response.
These both will returned response when the transaction status is `Confirmed`, but i want the fees, amount and blocktime (transaction time) in the `Processed` state.

I know it will take only few seconds to confirm the the transaction, but in my system i want them too early.

Can anyone help !

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the current validator implementation. Fetching a transaction requires getting it from the blockstore, which is not guaranteed to contain `processed` transactions. To make the returned data consistent, it requires at least that transactions are `confirmed`.

If you want transaction information earlier, you have a few options that all have tradeoffs.

- You can use the information contained in the transaction itself. For example, you can calculate the fee before sending the transaction using `getFeeForMessage` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getfeeformessage And for the amount, you can inspect the transaction
- Before sending the transaction, you can simulate it using `simulateTransaction` and pass in the account addresses whose state you want to know after, and log that state https://docs.solana.com/api/http#simulatetransaction -- unfortunately, this isn't guaranteed to be the state after actually executing the transaction